# Why this script about changing variables don't working? Unity 2D - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm recreating FNF and this is the note that go up in FNF.

Issue:
The switch of 'Type' variable doesn't work at all, it only works with the 'Left' Type.
And yes, i checked and all the game objects has the Type var with something.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Note : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float position;
    public KeyCode keyCode;
    public float speed;
    public string Type;
    public Color color;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type))
        {
            switch (Type)
            {
                case "Left":
                    keyCode = KeyCode.A;
                    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.magenta;
                    color = Color.magenta; 
                    break;
            
                case "Right":
                    keyCode = KeyCode.D;
                    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
                    color = Color.red; 
                    break;
                case "Up":
                    keyCode = KeyCode.W;
                    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
                    color = Color.green; 
                    break;
            
                case "Down":
                    keyCode = KeyCode.S;
                    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.cyan;
                    color = Color.cyan; 
                    break;
            }
        }
       
        if (transform.position.y > 6)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("chart_loader").GetComponent<chart>().notes.Remove(gameObject.GetComponent<Note>());
        }
    }
}
```

I trying changing it to if's, but it oly worked to the Left type.

Comment: Your `switch` is unreachable if `Type` is neither null nor empty...

Comment: But it isen't null, in the inspector it says that is 'Down' or 'Up' or 'Left' etc...

Comment: Then please fix the code in your question because it says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type))
> ```

Here you are saying if your string `Type` is null or empty then only you go to the switch cases but instead you need to do the opposite like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type))
```

You can do this more cleanly like this also

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type))
    return;

switch (Type)
{
    case "Left":
        keyCode = KeyCode.A;
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.magenta;
        color = Color.magenta; 
        break;
...
```